# isset $_post issue with mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, post

I'm just working on the Backend of a project an have a small problem with this snippet

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $cat_delete = "DELETE FROM category WHERE categoryid='".$_POST['id']."' ";
    $cat_delete_ex = mysql_query($cat_delete);}`
```

But if the id is set with post, nothing happens.

The mysql query is working when I delete the

```
if (isset($_POST['id']))
```

anyone have an idea ?

Comment: plz provide the source of you form

Comment: A `POST` variable that was sent via a form is always set, regardless if it was filled or not. Use `!empty( $_POST['id'] )` to check what's in there. Also you should really cast your posted ID to an `int` to avoid SQL injection: ` . (int) $_POST['id'] . `

Comment: do you have value in $_POST['id']

Comment: be aware you could be attacked with sql injections with this query...

Comment: just saw the code is working, had another twist in the code so the page wasn't showing the delete after post... thanks anyway guys !

Comment: post your $_POST array result (print_r($_POST))

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not sure if your method is safe or not, but I would do it like this, might even throw in a regex to check for just numbers if the id is numeric:

EDIT: I made a revision, since you are dealing with an ID, I will assume the ID is numeric only, so instead of escaping it, I just will strip out everything but numbers. This may be a better fit for your situation. I also converted the function to a class so you will be able to reuse the script for several types of sanitizing strings. Maybe its because I am an overachiever too, I don't know. ADD, OCD, etc. Blame it on that :)

```
$postID = isset($_POST['id']) ? sanitize::ID($_POST['id']) : '';

if (sanitize::email("test@example.com")){
    echo "Real email";
} else {
    echo "Fake email";
}

if ($postID != ''){
    $cat_delete = "DELETE FROM category WHERE categoryid='".$postID."' "; 
    $cat_delete_ex = mysql_query($cat_delete);
}

class sanitize{
    function ID($string){
        $string = preg_replace('/[^0-9,]|,[0-9]*$/','',$string);
        return $string;
    }
    # I added another sanitize function so you can see what you can do
    # with it. Add phone numbers, domain names, etc... Each one could
    # be called with sanitize::{FUNCTION}
    function email($string){
        if (!ereg("^[^@]{1,64}@[^@]{1,255}$", $string)) {
            return false;
        }
        $email_array = explode("@", $string);
        $local_array = explode(".", $email_array[0]);
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($local_array); $i++) {
            if (!ereg("^(([A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-][A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~\.-]{0,63})|(\"[^(\\|\")]{0,62}\"))$",$local_array[$i])) return false;
        }
        if (!ereg("^\[?[0-9\.]+\]?$", $email_array[1])) {
            $domain_array = explode(".", $email_array[1]);
            if (sizeof($domain_array) < 2) return false;
            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($domain_array); $i++) {
                if (!ereg("^(([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])|([A-Za-z0-9]+))$", $domain_array[$i])) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are using post for the id?(asking because is the right way, but i have one too many times

```
<form action="action.php?id=hereistheid"
```

which will bring the id in the $_GET not $_POST.
next the checking

```
$id=(int)$_POST['id'];
if($id)
{
//do smth
}
```